# Copy Rows adjacent to merged cell with checkbox and paste into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am writing a code but lack enough knowledge to pull off something so unique. I have a checkbox in a merged cell (see column T). We click a button, and it should only take the rows Y:AB of that merged area and copy / paste them into a new workbook. It should loop through all checkboxes, and paste only checked items below the next group.

I managed to do this with single rows just fine.[image: The test fields]

This is the code that works up until I mess with the merged cells. Not sure if I can try .MergeArea.Copy. Also note, working on Mac here.

````
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox


Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'where the data is
   Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
    If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
        shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row).Copy '...copy the corresponding range of data...
        With wsDest
            .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '...this only pastes into the first empty row in the destination sheet, which is an issue. Would prefer pasting starting on Y15
               .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 
                  .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths 
            
        End With
    End If
    Next cb
    End Sub ```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merged Cells are an annoyance when it comes to programming. The main thing you need to know is that if a cell is part of a merged area, you can use the property `MergedArea` of the cell.

Now all you need to do is figure out

- the *real* first row: Use `cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row`
- the number of rows you want to copy: Use `cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count`

Knowing that, your code could look like that

```
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
    ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.row) 
    Set sourceRange = sourceRange.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
    sourceRange.Copy    '...copy the corresponding range of data...
    With wsDest
        Dim row As Long
        row = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        With .Cells(row, "Y")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '...this only pastes into the first empty row in the destination sheet, which is an issue. Would prefer pasting starting on Y15
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    End With
End If
Next cb
```

Comment: @FunThomas Your code works perfectly! WOWWW. Thank you!! Just one question. Is there a way to start this overall count on Y15? Then resume the below code for the remaining selections? Dim row As Long row = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

Comment: You mean for the destination? For example with `If row < 15 Then row = 15`

Comment: @FunThomas, I think so. Essentially just starting the initial paste onto Y15. So it isn't pasting the list on first row.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @funThomas, here is the code, starting on row 15 of the new workbook (other stuff will be pasted above row 15), so this was an important change to specify where to start the code.

```
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox


Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
   Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
    ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
    Set sourceRange = sourceRange.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
    sourceRange.Copy    '...copy the corresponding range of data...
    With wsDest
        Dim row As Long
        row = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        If row < 15 Then row = 15
        With .Cells(row, "Y")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '...Paste info
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    End With
End If
Next cb
End Sub
```