# Get values to left and right of merged cell with checkbox VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

@FunThomas answered this in part I. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76439568/21278470

[image]

My question now, I am modifying the code to ALSO capture the ranges B:I to the left of the checkbox. Currently it is only set up for grabbing Y:AB

This is the code below that works correctly for grabbing only one range; however no matter how I try to modify it, it seems like it is setup only to have one range.

```
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox


Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
   Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
    ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
    Set sourceRange = sourceRange.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
    sourceRange.Copy    '...copy the corresponding range of data...
    With wsDest
        Dim row As Long
        row = .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        If row < 15 Then row = 15
        With .Cells(row, "Y")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '...Paste info
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
    End With
End If
Next cb
End Sub
```

I wrote the below VBA to copy the ranges B:I and Y:AB using union, but only the formatting is pasting, no text. And the Code only grabs one checkbox row instead of all checked rows.

Any way to modify the first code to grab multiple ranges of this merged row?

```
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox


Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
   Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
    ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
    Dim sourceRange1 As Range, sourceRange2 As Range, multiplerange As Range
    Set sourceRange1 = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
    Set sourceRange1 = sourceRange1.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
    Set sourceRange2 = shtSource.Range("B" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "I" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
    Set sourceRange2 = sourceRange2.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
    Set multiplerange = Application.Union(sourceRange1, sourceRange2)
    multiplerange.Copy    '...copy the corresponding range of data...
    
    With wsDest
        Dim row As Long
        row = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        If row < 15 Then row = 15
        With .Cells(row, "B")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats '...Paste info
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        
        End With
    End With
End If
Next cb
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I figured out the issue. I had to delete Destination:=wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B") and then everything is working now. Only issue: it will nnot accept paste column widths as a line item without overwriting everything. So to get around this, I added a separate copy and paste of just column widths AFTER the checkbox function finishes. This probably isn't the cleanest, but it is now a fully working solution.

```
Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim destRow As Long

Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

destRow = 15 ' starting row in the destination sheet

For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
    If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
        ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
        Dim sourceRange1 As Range, sourceRange2 As Range, multiplerange As Range
        Set sourceRange1 = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
        Set sourceRange1 = sourceRange1.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        Set sourceRange2 = shtSource.Range("B" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.row, "I" & cb.TopLeftCell.row)
        Set sourceRange2 = sourceRange2.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        Set multiplerange = Application.Union(sourceRange1, sourceRange2)
        
        multiplerange.Copy  ' copy and paste the range
        
        ' Paste formatting and column widths
        With wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        End With
        
        destRow = destRow + multiplerange.Rows.Count ' increment the destination row
        
    End If
Next cb

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear the clipboard

multiplerange.Copy
With wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With

Set wsDest = Nothing
Set wbDest = Nothing
Set shtSource = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing with the modified code is that you are copying the ranges correctly, but when pasting, you are pasting only in the B column of the destination sheet instead of the corresponding columns. Additionally, the code is not set up to handle multiple checked rows.

To modify the code to grab multiple ranges of the merged row and paste them correctly, you can make the following changes:

Replace the line With .Cells(row, "B") with With .Cells(row, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count). This will ensure that the data is pasted into the corresponding columns in the destination sheet.

To handle multiple checked rows, you can modify the code to copy and paste each range separately. Here's an updated version of the code:

code -

Sub copySelected()
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim destRow As Long

```
Set shtSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT") 'where the data is
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")

destRow = 15 ' starting row in the destination sheet

For Each cb In shtSource.CheckBoxes 'loop through all checkboxes
    If cb.Value = 1 Then 'if the checkbox has been selected then...
        ' Figure out the area of data we want to copy
        Dim sourceRange1 As Range, sourceRange2 As Range, multiplerange As Range
        Set sourceRange1 = shtSource.Range("Y" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "AB" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange1 = sourceRange1.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        Set sourceRange2 = shtSource.Range("B" & cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Row, "I" & cb.TopLeftCell.Row)
        Set sourceRange2 = sourceRange2.Resize(cb.TopLeftCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count)
        Set multiplerange = Application.Union(sourceRange1, sourceRange2)
        
        multiplerange.Copy Destination:=wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B") ' copy and paste the range
        
        ' Paste formatting and column widths
        With wsDest.Cells(destRow, "B").Resize(, multiplerange.Columns.Count)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        End With
        
        destRow = destRow + multiplerange.Rows.Count ' increment the destination row
        
    End If
Next cb

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' clear the clipboard

' AutoFit columns in the destination sheet if needed
wsDest.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit

Set wsDest = Nothing
Set wbDest = Nothing
Set shtSource = Nothing
```

End Sub

This updated code will copy and paste the ranges B:I and Y:AB for each checked row, aligning the data in the corresponding columns of the destination sheet. It will also increment the destination row appropriately to paste subsequent ranges.

Comment: Thanks @Angshunav this code executes only one row correctly but throws an error (I'm using mac). It still populates the workbook with the data now!!! but throws Runtime error 424, object required. And calls issue to the pastespecial codes.

Comment: this also means the code isn't pasting subsequent checked rows because it is timing out. I am trying to modify what you sent. It works with many modifications to the paste range, but ultimately throws same error.